# Cassandra - Nested Json Insert

Tags: json, cassandra

DSE 6.7
CentOS 6.7

We have data in JSON with the below format -

```
{ "Event_Type": "Booked", "Car": { "RegId": "0961dbac-297d-424c-96ce-9f37f1707cd9" } }

{ "Event_Type": "Complete", "Car": { "RegId": "0961dbac-297d-424c-96ce-9f37f1707cd9" } }

{ "Event_Type": "Booked", "Car": { "RegId": "b32f7b0b-d077-44c4-a454-519a3f82c759" } }

{ "Event_Type": "Complete", "Car": {"RegId": "b32f7b0b-d077-44c4-a454-519a3f82c759"} }

{ "Event_Type": "Booked", "Car": { "RegId": "6fa0b439-0782-49e8-9ac3-78c275470516" } }

{ "Event_Type": "Complete", "Car": { "RegId": "6fa0b439-0782-49e8-9ac3-78c275470516"} }
```

we need to insert into cassandra with the below table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "car"."car_appt" (

"event_type" text,

"RegId" uuid,

"timetamp" timestamp

);
```

Requried Output

```
Event_Type      RegId

Booked          0961dbac-297d-424c-96ce-9f37f1707cd9
Complete        0961dbac-297d-424c-96ce-9f37f1707cd9
Booked          b32f7b0b-d077-44c4-a454-519a3f82c759
Complete        b32f7b0b-d077-44c4-a454-519a3f82c759
```

I am unable to insert the above json, since it is inside a nested json.

Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra tries to put some structure around a non-structured row that you've supplied. You didn't specify "car", which is really what your reqId "belongs to", so it bombs. The best option is to create a type (so it can be used with the PK definition) and then create the table in the following way:

```
create type cartype (   
  regId text
);

create table car_appt (
  event_type text, 
  car frozen<cartype>, 
  timestamp timestamp, 
  primary key (event_type, car)
);
```

Once that's done, you're all set.

```
insert into car_appt JSON '{ "Event_Type": "Booked", "Car": { "RegId": "6fa0b439-0782-49e8-9ac3-78c275470516" } }';


select * from car_appt;



event_type | car
------------+-------------------------------------------------
     Booked | {regid: '6fa0b439-0782-49e8-9ac3-78c275470516'}
```

Also

```
select car.regId from car_appt;



car.regid
--------------------------------------
 6fa0b439-0782-49e8-9ac3-78c275470516
```

Like I said, this creates some structure around your data, where-as json itself is unstructured. This means you can't have some "rows" that have different fields in the nested document as it will fail. You need to have "car" and you need to have "regId" for all cassandra rows or it will fail. If this doesn't seem to work well for you, you may want to consider a document database instead (i.e. Mongo).

From your update, here is the output of the 6 inserts you provided. Other than the order, and the regid column heading, it looks the same.

```
select event_type, car.regId from car_appt;

 event_type | car.regid
------------+--------------------------------------
     Booked | 0961dbac-297d-424c-96ce-9f37f1707cd9
     Booked | 6fa0b439-0782-49e8-9ac3-78c275470516
     Booked | b32f7b0b-d077-44c4-a454-519a3f82c759
   Complete | 0961dbac-297d-424c-96ce-9f37f1707cd9
   Complete | 6fa0b439-0782-49e8-9ac3-78c275470516
   Complete | b32f7b0b-d077-44c4-a454-519a3f82c759
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your update. Your output shows 4 rows, but 6 inserts were done. Also, the output looks similar to what the table above provides, other than the column heading, which is close. Is that what's wrong? I'm trying to understand what is incorrect.  I've updated my answer with the output of the query with all of the rows you provided. The order of the rows is slightly different, but the answer is the same. Please provide additional information to what is incorrect.

Comment: Jim, all is correct. I updated the column attribute, how it should look like after your initial response.   Instead of car.regid, can we insert directly regid. i.e without  {regid: '6fa0b439-0782-49e8-9ac3-78c275470516'}, i want to insert 6fa0b439-0782-49e8-9ac3-78c275470516 in the car column

Comment: If you have a different insert scenario you want to test, paste it somewhere above. You can't just insert "regid". You're inserting JSON so the "structure/format" (and I use that loosely because JSON is a non-structured format) has to match your Cassandra table/type. Your original insert statements had "car: {regId....}", that has to match the Cassandra table/type in order to work. You can't switch your insert to something different. As is, the inserts you provided will work with the model I provided, and that model only (for JSON). The column heading looks a bit different, that's about it.